# Group by with several conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
user id   status     date 
1         accepted   1/10/2020
2         rejected   2/11/2020
3         accepted   3/8/2020
1         rejected   25/09/2020
3         accepted   11/10/2020
```

The output that i want :

```
user id   status     date          last operation   rejected 
1         accepted   1/10/2020          1              1
2         rejected   2/11/2020          0              0
3         accepted   3/8/2020           0              0
1         rejected   25/09/2020         0              0
3         accepted   11/10/2020         1              0
```

For the last operation column , i check for the same user id,  if there is row  with a date lower than the date on this user.
and rejected column , for the same user id if there is  a row with  lower date and status rejected

Thank you

Comment: answer was edited, can you test?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is compare minimal `date` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if not equal for `last` and for `rejected` is tested, if at least one matched minimal value is `rejected` with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for set all values of groups, last chain with `m1` with convert `True/False` to `1/0` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

EDIT:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values(['user id','date'])

s = df.groupby('user id')['date'].transform('min')
m1 = s.ne(df['date'])

m3 = df['status'].mask(m1).eq('rejected').groupby(df['user id']).transform('any')

df['last1'] =  m1.groupby(df['user id']).cumsum()
df['rejected1'] = df['last1'].where(m3, 0)

df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
```